# Deploying to Azure Analysis Services from Visual Studio resets the datasource 'path' property

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, datasource, sql-server-data-tools, azure-analysis-services

When deploying from Visual Studio SSDT to Azure Analysis Services, the deployment works fine. But when trying the process the deployed model from SSMS, the following error occurs:

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
    establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
    was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and
    that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections*

The server's instance name, properties are all intact and have worked correctly in the past. If I try to process the same model from Visual Studio SSDT before deployment, the process works perfectly fine and I can see the data I expect to see, which means there are no issues with the credentials or the settings.

On further investigation, scripting out the DataSource Connections on SSMS shows that for some reason, the 'path' property of the connection does not get deployed, while I have seen during past deployments that the 'path' property was indeed getting deployed.

The only difference between the previous deployments and the new deployment is the user performing the deployment onto AAS. The rest of the conditions are all the same.

What settings (for the user deploying it) could be affecting this? As I'm sure that the root cause for the error is that AAS is unable to access the DataSource server properly because of the missing path property. Does the user deploying it need to be an admin of the AAS database?

Answer (score 0):

It is a known behavior, in order to deploy credentials you need to use [TMLS script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference?view=asallproducts-allversions).